# Js lib initiate & sample code needed

Tags: javascript, initialization

I have been struggling instantiate js library, then call the initiate object> method call.

i  have to initiate js library exactly like this?

```
var objInstance = new banner.BannerLib({
‘name’: ‘topBanner’, 
‘size’: 30,
‘color’: ‘red’ 
});  // how will be the structure of banner, and bannerlib is constructor?
```

then call like this?

objInstance.show(); // show will be method in banner, how to define in banner?

question: 1. how will be lib/function structure for banner? can anyone give example code? 
Please remember i have to initiate code..exactly like that. not like   var ob = new banner();

Answer (score 1):

I try to make somethings

```
var banner ={};
banner.show = function(){
  console.log("show somethings");
};
banner.BannerLib = function(a){
    a || ( a = {});
    this.name = a.name || "Default Name";
    this.size = a.size || "Default Size";
    this.color = a.color || "BLUE";
    // Maybe something you need to initialize
};
banner.BannerLib.prototype.show = function(){

  banner.show();
};

var obj = new banner.BannerLib({"name":"test", "color":"red",'size':21});
```

Hope it'll help you

Comment: Great!  you just saved me :)